# what(): fail. could not find VmRSS

Tags: c++, memory, graph

The code I am trying to compile a .cpp file that generates a huge graph database. It is supposed to generate two TTL files; one for nodes and another for edges. I understand the graph is huge, hence the error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'MyException'
  what():  fail. could not find VmRSS
```

Is there anyway to fix it? I am already running as admin.

Comment: The issue doesn't seem to be about the large size but that it can't find VmRSS. Please show a [mre]. Unrelated: `MyException` is not a very good name for an exception type.

Comment: I figured that this exception is thrown because my file (that was originally written for linux environment) is trying to read the process status from /proc/self/status to obtain the VmRSS (Resident Set Size) information. I believe I should find an equivalent command for windows.

Comment: Yes, [`GetProcessMemoryInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/psapi/nf-psapi-getprocessmemoryinfo) is probably a good start.